# detectar error en un range y si la respuesta es correcta no continuar con el for

Tags: python, bucle-for, validación, while

estoy intentando hacer lo siguiente en python:
Un programa que solicite al usuario cuántos números se van a introducir y escriba cuántos negativos y cuántos positivos. PERO Si se ingresa un número negativo, decimal o carácter en "cuántos números se van a introducir" debo generar un letrero que diga "imposible" y vuelva a pedir "cuántos números se van a introducir" diez veces o hasta ingresar un número entero positivo y generar el programa.

He intentando con el siguiente código: pero no logro colocar bien el for para que sólo se repita 10 veces si hay un error. Si el programa recibe un número correcto no debe ejecutarse el programa 10 veces más.

````
#loop = True
while i in range(10):
  try:
    c_num = int (input ("¿Cuántos números va a introducir? "))

      if c_num < 0:  
        print('Imposible')
  except ValueError:
        print("Imposible")
  else:
        positivos = 0
        negativos = 0
        cero = 0       
for i in range (c_num):
      num = int(input('Ingrese el número: '))
      if num > 0:
        positivos +=1
      elif num < 0:
          negativo += 1
      else: 
          cero += 1
print ('Cantidad de positivos:', positivos)
print ('Cantidad de negativos:', negativos)
print ('Cantidad de ceros:', cero)```
````

Comment: Tu código no ejecuta; tiene errores de sintaxis. Revisalo, editalo y corrigelo.

Comment: en el `else` pon un `break` así se dejará de ejecutar. Por cierto, te falta pedir el número de positivos y negativos

Answer (score 0):

No sé si he entendido exactamente cual es tu problema. Veo que has puesto un ejemplo de código pero no sé si lo que pretendes es que ese mismo código funcione o si la duda es más genérica.

Dicho esto, te paso mi propuesta basada en tu código. Las principales diferencias son:

- he puesto las 2 partes de tu código en 2 funciones independientes. esto contribuye al 'Single-Responsibility Principle (SRP)' de python donde cada tarea tiene una única responsabilidad. y además nos ayuda para gestionar el flujo de tu programa. Más paso un [link](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-oop/python-single-responsibility-principle/) donde puedes profundizar en el SRP y en resto de ke principio SOLID de python.
- he potenciado el uso del `continue`/`break`/`else` del `for` para gestionar de forma mas eficiente el propio flujo del `for`. si te interesa, mira es [link](https://realpython.com/python-for-loop/) para profundizar mas en como gestionar un `for` loop.
- en la segunda parte, he almacenado todos los valores introducidos por el usuario y luego he contado los positivos/negativos/ceros. de esta manera puedes usar las mismas variables para hacer un contador (con la sentencia `len()`) y para saber los números que ha puesto el usuario.
- he usado también la creación de listas a través de 'list-comprehension'. Si tienes dudas de como funcionan mira este [link](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)

He puesto también muchos comentarios antes de cada linea de código para explicarte paso a paso el porqué de cada sentencia. Espero que esto te ayude. pero luego deberías eliminarlos cuando vayas a "productivizar" tu código para no llenarlo de tanta basura.

Para facilitarte la lectura, empieza por la fila que pone `# Tu programa empieza a ejecutar aqui`, luego leete la funcion `get_num_values()` y léete la función `calc_stats()` solo cuando la llamo dentro de `if num > 0:` del `get_num_values()`.

```
def calc_stats(c_num: int):

    # Guardamos todos los numeros introducidos en una lista
    # aqui faltaria saber que quieres hacer en caso de que el valor
    # introducido por el ususario no sea un numero entero, porque ahora mismo
    # devolveria un ValueError
    nums = [int(input('Ingrese el número: ')) for n in range(c_num)]

    # creamos sub-listas cada una con la condición que necesitas:
    positivos = [n for n in nums if n>0]
    negativos = [n for n in nums if n<0]
    ceros = [n for n in nums if n==0]

    # mostramos las estadíticas.
    # aqui he ampliado tu requerimiento para poner los numeros ademas del
    # contador de positivos/negativos/ceros (excepto para los ceros claro)
    print ('Cantidad de positivos:', len(positivos), 'valores:', positivos)
    print ('Cantidad de negativos:', len(negativos), 'valores:', negativos)
    print ('Cantidad de ceros:', len(ceros))


def get_num_values(max_tries: int):

    # Intentamos conseguir un valor valido, un máx de n veces (n=max_tries)
    for n in range(max_tries):

        # preguntamos al usuario y lo almacenamos en una variable el resultado
        c_num = input("¿Cuántos números va a introducir?")

        # si el valor no se puede convertir a un entero (int) mostramos el aviso
        # y saltamos a la siguiente pasada del for (con la instrucción 'continue')
        try:
            num = int(c_num)
        except ValueError:
            print('Imposible')
            continue

        # si es mayor que cero entonces llamamos a la funcion de calculo de
        # positivos/negativos/ceros, y a continuacion salimos del 'for' (con break)
        if num > 0:
            calc_stats(num)
            break

        # si no es mayor que cero mostramos aviso y dejamos que avance a la
        # siguiente pasada del for
        print('Imposible')

    else:

        # si ha terminado todo el for y no ha encontrado un valor valido en ninguno
        # del os n intentos, mostramos un aviso antes de terminar este bloque de
        # codigo.
        # Poner este 'else' al mimo nivel del 'for' significa que dentro del for no
        # ha encontrado ningun 'break'
        if n == max_tries:
            print(f"Has alcanzado el numero maximo de intentos ({max_tries})")

# ##########################################
# Tu programa empieza a ejecutar aqui
# ##########################################

max_intentos = 10

get_num_values(max_intentos)

print("Fin")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! me ayudó mucho!